# ASP.NET Forms Authentication expiring even with activity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC site which uses ASP.NET Formsauthentication I have the ticket set to expire after 20 minutes of inactivity. However it is expiring after 20 minutes no matter what.

I guess what I am asking is, is this the right functionality of it or do I have some issue and if so a solution to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the `slidingExpiration` to `true`? If that fixes it, I'll repost as an answer.

Comment: Does your site do any file uploading/modifying?

Comment: yes, we use uploadify when doing file uploads.. but we solved some issues with FF and Safari for that.

Comment: Btw slidingExpiration seems to work

Comment: Yeah, `slidingExpiration` means that the expiration timer restarts with activity. If it is `false` then it will expire 20 minutes after being set, regardless of activity.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following

1) slidingExpiration = true
2) The login is not being dropped after an app recycle.
3) Also setting the machineKey explicitly in your web.config if you are in a shared environment